# Angular accessing element using viewchild not working

Tags: angular, viewchild

I have the following html input element (extracted)

```
<input type="text" #newName required />
```

This is of-course nested deep down in the template tree.  I'm trying to get access to this element and set the focus in my angular component.  To that end I have tried

```
@ViewChild('newName') newName: ElementRef;
```

However this returns null.  I also tried adding an id like this

```
<input type="text" id="newName" required />
```

But both these cases return `null`.  I am trying to get access to the element on the `click event`.

Comment: What does the template of this component look like? Is input inside of another component or in this component's template?

Comment: On what element is the click event ?

Comment: the input is inside the template itself, not inside another template.

Comment: add more code in your html, the above should work actually

Comment: actually I figured it out, it was hidden behind an `ngIf` later only I realized that this is not accessible.  Changed to use `Hidden` now it works.